# Let $f$ be Lebesgue measurable on $[0,1]$. Show that $\|f(\sqrt{x})\|_1\leq\frac{7}{6}\|f\|_2 $

Tags: real-analysis, lebesgue-integral

Let $f$ be Lebesgue measurable on $[0,1]$. Show that $\|f(\sqrt{x})\|_1\leq\frac{7}{6}\|f\|_2 $

The first part of the problem asks to show the bound $\|f(\sqrt{x})\|_1\leq2\|f\|_1 $ which is easy by doing $u$-sub. To be honest, I am not even sure if we can claim $f(\sqrt{x})$  is measurable. The problems says $f$ is Lebesgue measurable (not Borel measurble).

Any hints would be appreciated, I am not sure how to tackle it. I tried messing around with sets where $|f|\geq1$ and $|f|<1$ but could not get anything.

Comment: Hint: Change variables to $\sqrt{x}$ and then apply Holder's inequality

Comment: @Zarrax Thank you! So simple and I missed it, I guess I was expecting something more elaborate... How would I justify the function being measurable?

Comment: It follows from change of variables for example on any $[\epsilon, 1]$. Then taking unions in an appropriate fashion gives it on the whole interval $[0,1]$.